# Deployment lifecycle when init method is called

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hi I am newbie to Servlet/JSP/Springs .Wanted to know

I have a ear file which I deploy on weblogic server . Now as part of this ear some modules are exposed as webservice.

Now I have spring bean in the above mentioned ear  on which init method I am trying to access the webservice method's which should be exposed as part of deployment of this particular ear.

Will I be able to access the webservice or yet till init method is called the modules are not exposed as  webservice

So basically when I do the deployment first the init method of spring bean will be executed or
the modules which should get exposed as webservices will get exposed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The init method will be executed first during which your web service will be initialized after which the web service will get exposed.

Comment: My requirement is I want to execute a method which uses this exposed webservice and this method should get executed only once when the application  is deployed